# Get method the attribute is attached to, without looping through every class and method

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a project where methods are directly connected to equivalent strings.

Like `ListConnections()` is connected to `listconnections`.

The issue I'm having is - is there a more efficient way to get methods with `this` attribute instance rather than looping through all methods, then looping through their custom attributes and finally comparing unique properties of the attribute to get the method?

Something like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MethodStrAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Command { get; set; }

    public MethodInfo Method
    {
        get
        {
            //get method attached to `this` attribute instance
        }
    }
}
```

Because in such case, I wouldn't have to loop through all methods but instead get all attributes, then do `Where(x => x.Command == cmd).SingleOrDefault()?.Method.Invoke()`

## edit

Example usage of the attribute:

```
    [MethodStr("listconnections")]
    public static void ListConnections()
    {

    }
```

Comment: Please show how you expect to use the attribute. You likely don't need to do what you think you need to do.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've edited the post, it should be a bit more clearer now.

Comment: It's not. Show a usage of the attribute. In other words, is it something like `[Method("listconnections")] public void ListConnections() { ... }`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, it's exactly like this.